# Easiest way to sign/certify text file in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, certificate, pgp

I want to verify if the text log files created by my program being run at my customer's site have been tampered with. How do you suggest I go about doing this?  I searched a bunch here and google but couldn't find my answer. Thanks!

Edit:  After reading all the suggestions so far here are my thoughts. I want to keep it simple, and since the customer isn't that computer savy, I think it is safe to embed the salt in the binary. I'll continue to search for a simple solution using the keywords "salt checksum hash" etc and post back here once I find one.

Comment: Why does this have the "gpgpu" tag? GPGPU usually stands for General Purpose computing on Graphical Processing Units. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 5):

*Obligatory preamble:* How much is at stake here? You must assume that tampering will be  possible, but that you can make it very difficult if you spend enough time and money. So: how much is it worth to you?

That said:

Since it's your code writing the file, you can write it out encrypted. If you need it to be human readable, you can keep a second encrypted copy, or a second file containing only a hash, or write a hash value for every entry. (The hash must contain a "secret" key, of course.) If this is too risky, consider transmitting hashes or checksums or the log itself to other servers. And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite difficult thing to do, unless you can somehow protect the keypair used to sign the data.  Signing the data requires a private key, and if that key is on a machine, a person can simply alter the data or create new data, and use that private key to sign the data.  You can keep the private key on a "secure" machine, but then how do you guarantee that the data hadn't been tampered with before it left the original machine?

Of course, if you are protecting only data in motion, things get a lot easier.

Signing data is easy, if you can protect the private key.

Once you've worked out the higher-level theory that ensures security, take a look at [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/) to do the signing.

Comment: Could I embed the private key into the binary? 

I'm sure this has been done before and there is a known easy process for doing this. I just can't find it on google or here :(

Comment: It might be trivial to spot the key by looking at the binary in a hex editor.

Comment: @user355008: Embedding a key inside something won't help. If you app can see the key in some way, then a user can too.

Answer (score 1):

You may put a checksum as a prefix to each of your file lines, using an algorithm like [adler-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) or something.
If you do not want to put binary code in your log files, use an encode64 method to convert the checksum to non binary data. So, you may discard only the lines that have been tampered.

Comment: How would this prevent an attacker from just recomputing the checksum?

Comment: From the wiki page you shared it says "the Adler-32 checksum can be forged easily and is therefore unsafe for protecting against intentional modification". So I don't think this will work. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't know the level of security required, so i wrote "like adler-32 or something". You can even use adler-32, md5 128 bits or sha1 hashing methods with salting, by adding your own key to the string to be encrypted. So will be very hard for someone to recompute the correct checksum.

Comment: Of course then the very heart of the matter is: how do you hide the key and salting process from the customer since it's packed in the binary thus submitted to possible deassembly examination ? :p

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Ask them politely not to look :)

Comment: If you really need a very strong cryptograph model, use Public-key cryptography. This technique uses asymmetric key algorithms based on 2 keys, where the key used to encrypt a message is not the same as the key used to decrypt it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, what is at stakes and what are the constraints.

Fundamentally: what you are asking for is just plain impossible (in isolation).

Now, it's a matter of complicating the life of the persons trying to modify the file so that it'll cost them more to modify it than what they could earn by doing the modification. Of course it means that hackers motivated by the sole goal of cracking in your measures of protection will not be deterred that much...

Assuming it should work on a standalone computer (no network), it is, as I said, impossible. Whatever the process you use, whatever the key / algorithm, this is ultimately embedded in the binary, which is exposed to the scrutiny of the would-be hacker. It's possible to deassemble it, it's possible to examine it with hex-readers, it's possible to probe it with different inputs, plug in a debugger etc... Your only option is thus to make debugging / examination a pain by breaking down the logic, using debug detection to change the paths, and if you are very good using self-modifying code. It does not mean it'll become impossible to tamper with the process, it barely means it should become difficult enough that any attacker will abandon.

If you have a network at your disposal, you can store a hash on a distant (under your control) drive, and then compare the hash. 2 difficulties here:

- Storing (how to ensure it is your binary ?)
- Retrieving (how to ensure you are talking to the right server ?)

And of course, in both cases, beware of the man in the middle syndroms...

One last bit of advice: if you need security, you'll need to consult a real expert, don't rely on some strange guys (like myself) talking on a forum. We're amateurs.

Answer (score 0):

It's your file and your program which is allowed to modify it. When this being the case, there is one simple solution. (If you can afford to put your log file into a seperate folder)

*Note:*
You can have all your log files placed into a seperate folder. For eg, in my appplication, we have lot of DLLs, each having it's own log files and ofcourse application has its own.

So have a seperate process running in the background and monitors the folder for any changes notifications like

- change in file size
- attempt to rename the file or folder
- delete the file
  etc...

Based on this notification, you can certify whether the file is changed or not!
(As you and others may be guessing, even your process & dlls will change these files that can also lead to a notification. You need to synchronize this action smartly. That's it)

Window API to monitor folder in given below:

```
HANDLE FindFirstChangeNotification(
LPCTSTR lpPathName,
BOOL bWatchSubtree,
DWORD dwNotifyFilter
);

lpPathName: 
Path to the log directory.

bWatchSubtree:
Watch subfolder or not (0 or 1)

dwNotifyFilter:
Filter conditions that satisfy a change notification wait. This parameter can be one or more of the following values. 
FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME
FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME
FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE
FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY
etc... 
(Check MSDN)
```

**How to make it work?**

*Suspect A*: Our process

*Suspect X*: Other process or user

*Inspector*: The process that we created to monitor the folder.

*Inpector* sees a change in the folder. Queries with *Suspect A* whether he did any change to it.

if so,

```
change is taken as VALID.
```

if not

```
clear indication that change is done by *Suspect X*. So NOT VALID! 
File is certified to be TAMPERED.
```

Other than that, below are some of the techniques that may (or may not :)) help you!

1. Store the time stamp whenever an application close the file along with file-size. 
   The next time you open the file, check for the last modified time of the time and its size. If both are same, then it means file remains not tampered.
2. Change the file privilege to *read-only* after you write logs into it. In some program or someone want to tamper it, they attempt to change the read-only property. This action changes the date/time modified for a file.
3. Write to your log file only encrypted data. If someone tampers it, when we decrypt the data, we may find some text not decrypted properly.
4. Using compress and un-compress mechanism (compress may help you to protect the file using a password)

Each way may have its own pros and cons. Strength the logic based on your need. You can even try the combination of the techniques proposed.

Comment: For point 1 and point 2: It is easy to set the modification time of a file, and change the contents of a file without changing its length. For point 3 and point 4: you must understand that if your application can perform these tasks, then a user can too (simply by mimicking what the application does).

Comment: @dreamlax: All those points provided just to give some insight to the intended users. I know all of it has loop holes. The primary focus is on the DATA provided above those silly (if you look it that way) points!